# Get assigning var from mouse clicked

Tags: java, mouselistener, mouseclick-event

So this is how it works, I add a mouse clicked method and when it is clicked then `alreadyClicked = true;` then I check var alreadyClicked which should be true with a conditional in main or constructor `if (alreadyClicked == true){ System.out.println("True");}`.

And somehow the output doesn't print, it's like I can't get the variable assignment from my mouseClicked method. Or maybe it's just me who's wrong

for note: i already declare Boolean alreadyClicked in global

```
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    alreadyClicked = true;}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    if (myClass.alreadyClicked){
        System.out.println("true");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: alright, sorry about that

Comment: Well, you have to click. To work with click handlers, you have to follow an event-based approach – they are not and cannot be executed sequentially. They are not waiting for the click to happen before executing the following code; instead it is executed immediately

Comment: `System.out.println(Boolean.toString(alreadyClicked));`